# How to pass multiple automatic reponses to user prompts between batch files using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, script, shell-script

I am trying to setup a system that allows for users to be able to format a script that in turn calls other scripts or commands that they include in this script.

On Linux I have it working using:

```
cat > startup.sh <<'EOF' 
chmod +x  ./apply_my_settings.sh  
/bin/bash -c "yes | ./apply_my_settings.sh" 
EOF
```

I can then use the command:

```
chmod +x ./startup.sh 
./startup.sh
```

And the startup script will run with 'yes' being automatically answered to the user-input prompts put by `apply_my_settings.sh`.

What I cannot seem to work out is how to get a similar setup working on powershell with batch files.

I have tried numerous different setups and gotten some conflicting results. For example
`'y', 'y', 'N' | .\apply_my_settings.bat` successfully pipes `y`, `y`, `N` to the prompts in `apply_my_settings.bat`. But when I try

```
New-Item .\startup.bat -type file
"`'y`', `'y`', `'N`' | .\apply_my_settings.bat" >> .\startup.bat
```

And later try to run the startup file with `.\startup.bat` the scripts fail to receive the piped responses.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I have tried workarounds including syntax swaps, populating the `statup.bat` file with `(echo y && echo echo y && echo N ) | ...`  instead of the letters and also just `echo 'y' | ...`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look into `expect` or specifically its [windows ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276561/expect-like-tool-for-windows). It will enable you to send input based on the scripts expected output, without being limited to just send input sequentially and possibly fail because of a delay.

Comment: The issue here is when you run the `.bat` file it will run using `cmd` which has a different interpreter than `PowerShell`, for example the method you've used to pass the array will not work in `cmd` and is why the `statup.bat` fails. For a simpler life, pick one, either `cmd` and `bat` or `PowerShell` and `ps1`.

Comment: I second what jfrmilner says. But I advocate for PowerShell only if possible since it's the future so might as well if you're starting from scratch. Not sure what your startup.bat contains, but disclosing that may help others help you interpret its logic to pure PowerShell without cmd dependencies and thus some parameter with an equivalent result.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your suggestions and help. I will look into all of your recommendations. Right now, the statup file is installing demo certificates for sign-on. The file asks if the user would like to run it; would like to use the demo certificates (warns them of the risks); and finally if they would like to run some extra server configuration steps. 

I would expect responses of "Y, Y, N" but want to make sure people 1) can input answers 2) can change the contents of the script (it is fine if they must require a server restart).

Comment: Given This statement: "but want to make sure people 1) can input answers 2) can change the contents of the script", if your still planning on using batch it seems more appropriate to use the choice command with the `/D` and `/T` switches to enact defaults if the user doesn't provide a response within the allowed time.